# EF core how to make relations using array?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have some entities

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Guid[] TagIds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How to build relations if posts.tag_ids is uuid[]?
I want to use

```
_dbContext.Posts.Include(x => x.Tags)
```

Expecting SQL

```
select * from posts p
left join tags t on t.id = any(p.tag_ids)
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Comment: I need relation, not convention

Answer (score 0):

This

```
public Guid[] TagIds { get; set; }
```

is not how relational databases model relationships.  If you want to relate the entities, try this instead:

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

It will create a linking table behind the scenes.

Comment: I have existing table with arrays

Comment: Then you need a Value Conversion.  EF just doesn't have the ability to map a Navigation Collection that uses an array of keys.